# Difference between dot and operator notation Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to know the difference between dot and operator notation in Ruby. Here are some examples

```
# Use dot notation to invoke a method 
"I'm thirty one characters long!".length
# => 31

# Use operator notation to invoke a method
"Kit" + "tens!"
# => "Kittens!"
```

Since both call a method and return similar objects, I suspect either the dot notation or operator method is more efficient. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: For some methods you won't find an operator notation or dot notation. For example `5.add(3)` unless you implement it. Another example would be invoking .length method with operator - you can not do that. When talking about efficiency we should actually have something to compare. We could do it if you provided an example with method called both ways.

Comment: a first thought: benchmark them (ruby even have a builtin benchmark module)

Comment: "Since both call a method and return similar objects, I suspect either the dot notation or operator method is more efficient." – I don't follow your logic: you are basically saying "since both do the same exact same thing, one must be more efficient". But that makes no sense: if they both do the exact same thing, you would expect them to be exactly equally efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] if we call methods on objects using that dot `.` notation, then where are the dots in `2 + 3 * 4`?
>
> The trick is: Ruby adds them for you, silently. If you write the following code:
>
> ```
> number = 2 + 3 * 4
> ```
>
> Then Ruby will translate this to the following:
>
> ```
> number = 2.+(3.*(4))
> ```
>
> -- [Operators are methods | Ruby for Beginners](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/operators/methods.html)

As for the performance difference:

```
# bmbm_dot_vs_operators.rb
require "benchmark"

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("dots") { 2.+(3.*(4)) }
  x.report("operators") { 2 + 3 * 4 }

  x.report("operators") { 4 + 2 * 3 }
  x.report("dots") { 4.+(2.*(3)) }
end
```

When ran on my system (MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)), it produces the following results

```
$ ruby bmbm_dot_vs_operators.rb
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
dots        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
operators   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
operators   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
dots        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
------------------------------------ total: 0.000000sec

                user     system      total        real
dots        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
operators   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
operators   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
dots        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000002)
```

The results are inconclusive.

There little to no measurable difference in performance when using inline operators over their dot method equivalents.

*Also, the first operation is always the slowest, hence why it was included multiple times for comparison of benchmarking order.*

**References:**

- [Module: Benchmark (Ruby 2.0.0)](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bmbm)

Comment: Thank you @sonna. Your explanation was superb.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Operator notation is syntactic sugar for dot notation. I would not expect any noticeable performance differences.

If you look at [Ruby's grammar](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y), you'll find the following:

```
call_bin_op(recv,id,arg1) call_bin_op_gen(parser, (recv),(id),(arg1))
```

This basically says that binary operators like `+` in your example, have a receiver, an ID (think of that as CRuby for a symbol) and an argument, just like a method call with one argument.

If you then look at `call_bin_op_gen`, you'll see that it actually translates to a call:

```
static NODE *
call_bin_op_gen(struct parser_params *parser, NODE *recv, ID id, NODE *arg1)
{
    value_expr(recv);
    value_expr(arg1);
    return NEW_CALL(recv, id, NEW_LIST(arg1));
}
```